# Check if an observable is complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to show a toast after an observable is complete, how i can do it, my code is:

```
this.commerceCtrl.UpdateCategories(this.toSave).subscribe(data => {
  }, error => {
    this.mainFunction.showError(error)
  }),
  complete => {
    this.mainFunction.showToast(this.localization.message_ok)
  }
```

I tried to do like this:

```
this.commerceCtrl.UpdateCategories(this.toSave).subscribe(data => {
  }, error => {
    this.mainFunction.showError(error)
  }),
  () => {
    this.mainFunction.showToast(this.localization.message_ok)
  }
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass the `complete` handler as the third argument to subscribe.

In your code, simply move the closing parenthesis to the end.

Change this code:

```
this.commerceCtrl.UpdateCategories(this.toSave).subscribe(data => {
  }, error => {
    this.mainFunction.showError(error)
  }), // <===== Remove this parenthesis
  () => {
    this.mainFunction.showToast(this.localization.message_ok)
  }; // <====== It should be here
```

To this:

```
this.commerceCtrl.UpdateCategories(this.toSave).subscribe(
  data => {
    // next handler body
  }, error => {
    this.mainFunction.showError(error)
  }, () => {
    this.mainFunction.showToast(this.localization.message_ok)
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give object parameter to `subscribe()` function:

```
this.commerceCtrl.UpdateCategories(this.toSave).subscribe({
   next: value => { ... },
   error: err => { ... },
   complete: () => { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **finally** method

```
this.commerceCtrl.UpdateCategories(this.toSave).finally(() => {
    // complete
}).subscribe((data) => {
    // success
}, (error) => {
    // error
});
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7865#issuecomment-204408637